# handle operating system restart and shutdown in electron by an API call before restart and shutdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

> How do I have an API call before the operating system restarts or shuts down in electron

Answer (score 2):

Use node's [process exit event](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#event_exit_) to run code when the process is exiting, which happens when a system shutdown or restart occurs.

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    // Shutdown logic
});
```

Obviously this will not work in the even of a "hard restart" or power loss, as those immediately terminate all processes. It will only with a graceful shutdown / restart.

Comment: this is not triggered on restart in windows 10. I am not too sure why.

Answer (score 1):

See the `session-end` event on the `BrowserWindow`:

The [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#event-session-end-windows) state:

> Emitted when window session is going to end due to force shutdown or
>   machine restart or session log off.